# How to Generate data in textbox Create data in gridline Grid Kendo UI

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-grid

I want to insert data from GridLine. i have 3 column (code, expDate, status). In code field i want to generate a word that consist of random character and number. And the voucher code editable is off. And in status will have only valid condition. And i want to make it in Grid Kendo UI. Help i don't know how to do it.

[image]

I'm using this code in my view. Help me to custom it. Thank you.

View

```
<div class="tables">
    <div class="table-responsive bs-example widget-shadow">
        <h4>Data Propinsi:</h4>
            @(Html.Kendo().Grid<admission.Models.VoucherPreviewModel>()
    .Name("grids")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.id_voucher).Hidden();
        columns.Bound(p => p.voucherCode).Title("Kode Voucher");
        columns.Bound(p => p.expDate).Title("Tgl Exp").Format("{0: dd MMM yyyy - HH:mm WIB}");
        columns.Bound(p => p.status).Title("Status");
        columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); }).Width(250);
    })
    .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Filterable()
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:570px;" })
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(10)
        .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
        .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.id_voucher))
        .Create(update => update.Action("voucher_Create", "Voucher")).Read("voucher_read", "Voucher")
        .Update(update => update.Action("voucher_Update", "Voucher")).Read("voucher_read", "Voucher")
        .Read(read => read.Action("voucher_read", "Voucher"))
        .Destroy(update => update.Action("voucher_Delete", "Voucher")).Read("voucher_read", "Voucher")
    )
)
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function error_handler(e) {    
        if (e.errors) {
            var message = "Errors:\n";
            $.each(e.errors, function (key, value) {
                if ('errors' in value) {
                    $.each(value.errors, function() {
                        message += this + "\n";
                    });
                }
            });        
            alert(message);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call a javascript function when the add/edit button is clicked. In javascript you can manipulate the datasource the way you like.

```
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                .Ajax()
                .PageSize(10)
                .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
                .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.id_voucher))
                .Create(update => update.Action("voucher_Create", "Voucher")).Read("voucher_read", "Voucher")
                .Update(update => update.Action("voucher_Update", "Voucher")).Read("voucher_read", "Voucher")
                .Read(read => read.Action("voucher_read", "Voucher"))
                .Destroy(update => update.Action("voucher_Delete", "Voucher")).Read("voucher_read", "Voucher")
            )
    .Events(events => events.Edit("onEdit"))

**.Events(events => events.Edit("onEdit"))**      

in javascript:

        function onEdit(event) {
            var grid = $("#ActionsGrid").data("kendoGrid");
            var dataSource=grid.dataSource;
            //do stuff here
           event.model.voucherCode=Math.random();//http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_random.asp
         //make row uneditable follow this thread: http://www.telerik.com/forums/making-individual-rows-read-only
        }
```

Apparently you cannot make the row uneditable but you can replace the html in that row. http://www.telerik.com/forums/making-individual-rows-read-only

Example with your code:

```
<div class="tables">
    <div class="table-responsive bs-example widget-shadow">
        <h4>Data Propinsi:</h4>
            @(Html.Kendo().Grid<admission.Models.VoucherPreviewModel>()
    .Name("grids")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.id_voucher).Hidden();
        columns.Bound(p => p.voucherCode).Title("Kode Voucher");
        columns.Bound(p => p.expDate).Title("Tgl Exp").Format("{0: dd MMM yyyy - HH:mm WIB}");
        columns.Bound(p => p.status).Title("Status");
        columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); }).Width(250);
    })
    .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Filterable()
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:570px;" })
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(10)
        .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
        .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.id_voucher))
        .Create(update => update.Action("voucher_Create", "Voucher")).Read("voucher_read", "Voucher")
        .Update(update => update.Action("voucher_Update", "Voucher")).Read("voucher_read", "Voucher")
        .Read(read => read.Action("voucher_read", "Voucher"))
        .Destroy(update => update.Action("voucher_Delete", "Voucher")).Read("voucher_read", "Voucher")
    )
    .Events(events => events.Edit("onEdit"))
)
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function error_handler(e) {    
        if (e.errors) {
             var message = "Errors:\n";
             $.each(e.errors, function (key, value) {
             if ('errors' in value) {
               $.each(value.errors, function() {
                     message += this + "\n";
                    });
                  }
                });        
                alert(message);
        }
}

function onEdit(event) {
               event.model.voucherCode=makeid();
            }

function makeid() {
    var code = "";
    var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    code = Math.random(1).toString().substring(3, 2);
    code += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
    return code;
}
    </script>
```

For the making the row uneditable part follow the thread i mentioned.

Comment: can u give me more detail explanation. I'm new in this. How can i get the random code and put it in the code textbox when update or create and make it become non-editable. Thanks

Comment: can i display the data from math.random right after i hit create new data??

Comment: Yes, i would say, try it. It's not hard. You have your model available in the javascript.

Comment: can u give me an example?

Comment: Did manage to get it working. I added the example how it should be in like in your code

Comment: it work, thank you
when i click create new record, can i put the generate in the textbox?? so i can see it first before click update . .

Comment: The javascript onEdit should be called when the add button is clicked. But I'm not sure, i don't have a working example of your situation. Please mark the this as answer if this solved your problem. If you have more questions or other question please create a new question.